# No internet connection on last update

Tags: networking, updates, internet, ethernet, realtek-wireless

My laptop did the latest update and when did the restart the WiFi and wired connection are not functioning any more.
I'm use Ubuntu 18.04 LST and the laptop is a Hp with AMD Ryzen 5 CPU

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and am still trying to figure it out. I did figure out if I disabled the fire wall using "sudo ufw disable" I was able to connect. I tried setting it back to default settings but every time I enable it, I can't connect. Hope this helps.